# C# Примеры использования класса Extreme.Numerics

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть примеры использования Extreme.Numerics
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extreme.Numerics/

Мне нужно использовать его для расчета определенного интеграла от функции одной переменной и хотелось бы увидеть какие нибудь примеры, чтобы разобраться

Comment: https://www.extremeoptimization.com/ Сайт не работает

Comment: у меня сайт работает. Но я с украины на него стучусь, видимо он недоступен с твоего региона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример ***Basic Integration QuickStart Sample (C#)*** доступный [по этому адресу](https://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/BasicIntegration.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System;

namespace Extreme.Numerics.QuickStart.CSharp
{
    // The numerical integration classes reside in the
    // Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus namespace.
    using Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus;
    // Function delegates reside in the Extreme.Mathematics
    // namespace.
    using Extreme.Mathematics;
    using Extreme.Mathematics.Algorithms;

    /// <summary>
    /// Illustrates the basic use of the numerical integration
    /// classes in the Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus namespace of the Extreme
    /// Optimization Mathematics Library for .NET.
    /// </summary>
    class BasicIntegration
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Numerical integration algorithms fall into two
            // main categories: adaptive and non-adaptive.
            // This QuickStart Sample illustrates the use of
            // the non-adaptive numerical integrators.
            //
            // All numerical integration classes derive from
            // NumericalIntegrator. This abstract base class
            // defines properties and methods that are shared
            // by all numerical integration classes.

            //
            // The integrand
            //

            // The function we are integrating must be
            // provided as a Func<double, double>. For more
            // information about this delegate, see the
            // FunctionDelegates QuickStart sample.
            Func<double, double> f = Math.Sin;
            // Variable to hold the result:
            double result;

            //
            // SimpsonIntegrator
            // 

            // The simplest numerical integration algorithm
            // is Simpson's rule. 
            SimpsonIntegrator simpson = new SimpsonIntegrator();
            // You can set the relative or absolute tolerance
            // to which to evaluate the integral.
            simpson.RelativeTolerance = 1e-5;
            // You can select the type of tolerance using the
            // ConvergenceCriterion property:
            simpson.ConvergenceCriterion =
                ConvergenceCriterion.WithinRelativeTolerance;
            // The Integrate method performs the actual 
            // integration:
            result = simpson.Integrate(f, 0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("sin(x) on [0,2]");
            Console.WriteLine("Simpson integrator:");
            // The result is also available in the Result 
            // property:
            Console.WriteLine("  Value: {0}", simpson.Result);
            // To see whether the algorithm ended normally,
            // inspect the Status property:
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}", simpson.Status);
            // You can find out the estimated error of the result
            // through the EstimatedError property:
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", simpson.EstimatedError);
            // The number of iterations to achieve the result
            // is available through the IterationsNeeded property.
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}", simpson.IterationsNeeded);
            // The number of function evaluations is available 
            // through the EvaluationsNeeded property.
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}", simpson.EvaluationsNeeded);

            //
            // Gauss-Kronrod Integration
            //

            // Gauss-Kronrod integrators also use a fixed point 
            // scheme, but with certain optimizations in the 
            // choice of points where the integrand is evaluated.

            // The NonAdaptiveGaussKronrodIntegrator uses a
            // succession of 10, 21, 43, and 87 point rules
            // to approximate the integral.
            NonAdaptiveGaussKronrodIntegrator nagk =
                new NonAdaptiveGaussKronrodIntegrator();
            nagk.Integrate(Math.Sin, 0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Non-adaptive Gauss-Kronrod rule:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value: {0}", nagk.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}", nagk.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", nagk.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}", nagk.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}", nagk.EvaluationsNeeded);

            //
            // Romberg Integration
            //

            // Romberg integration combines Simpson's Rule
            // with a scheme to accelerate convergence.
            // This algorithm is useful for smooth integrands.
            RombergIntegrator romberg = new RombergIntegrator();
            result = romberg.Integrate(Math.Sin, 0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Romberg integration:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value: {0}", romberg.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}", romberg.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", romberg.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}", romberg.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}", romberg.EvaluationsNeeded);

            // However, it breaks down if the integration
            // algorithm contains singularities or 
            // discontinuities.
            //
            // The AdaptiveIntegrator can handle this type
            // of integrand, and many other difficult cases.
            // See the AdvancedIntegration QuickStart sample
            // for details.
            result = romberg.Integrate(x => x <= 0.0 ? 0.0 : Math.Pow(x, -0.9) * Math.Log(1 / x),
                0.0, 1.0);
            Console.WriteLine("Romberg on hard integrand:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value: {0}", romberg.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Actual value: 100");
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}", romberg.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", romberg.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}", romberg.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}", romberg.EvaluationsNeeded);

            Console.Write("Press Enter key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Function that will cause difficulties to the
        /// simplistic integration algorithms.
        /// </summary>
        private static double HardIntegrand(double x)
        {
            // This is put in because some integration rules
            // evaluate the function at x=0.
            if (x <= 0)
                return 0;
            return Math.Pow(x, -0.9) * Math.Log(1 / x);
        }
    }
}
```

А это пример ***Advanced Integration QuickStart Sample (C#)***:

```
using System;

namespace Extreme.Numerics.QuickStart.CSharp
{
    // The numerical integration classes reside in the
    // Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus namespace.
    using Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus;
    // Function delegates reside in the Extreme.Mathematics
    // namespace.
    using Extreme.Mathematics;

    /// <summary>
    /// Illustrates the more advanced use of the 
    /// AdaptiveGaussKronrodIntegrator numerical integrator class
    /// classes in the Extreme.Mathematics.Calculus namespace of the Extreme
    /// Optimization Numerical Libraries for .NET.
    /// </summary>
    class AdvancedIntegration
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Numerical integration algorithms fall into two
            // main categories: adaptive and non-adaptive.
            // This QuickStart Sample illustrates the use of
            // the adaptive numerical integrator implemented by
            // the AdaptiveIntegrator class. This class is the
            // most advanced of the numerical integration 
            // classes.
            //
            // All numerical integration classes derive from
            // NumericalIntegrator. This abstract base class
            // defines properties and methods that are shared
            // by all numerical integration classes.

            //
            // The integrand
            //

            // The function we are integrating must be
            // provided as a Func<double, double>. For more
            // information about this delegate, see the
            // FunctionDelegates QuickStart sample.
            //
            // Variable to hold the result:
            double result;
            // Construct an instance of the integrator class:
            AdaptiveIntegrator integrator = new AdaptiveIntegrator();

            //
            // Adaptive integrator basics
            //

            // All the properties and methods defined by the
            // NumericalIntegrator base class are available.
            // See the BasicIntegration QuickStart Sample 
            // for details. The AdaptiveIntegrator class defines
            // the following additional properties:
            //
            // The IntegrationRule property gets or sets the
            // integration rule that is to be used for
            // integrating subintervals. It can be any
            // object derived from IntegrationRule.
            //
            // For convenience, a series of Gauss-Kronrod
            // integration rules of order 15, 21, 31, 41, 51, 
            // and 61 have been provided.
            integrator.IntegrationRule = IntegrationRule.CreateGaussKronrod15PointRule();
            // The UseAcceleration property specifies whether
            // precautions should be taken for singularities
            // in the integration interval.
            integrator.UseExtrapolation = false;
            // Finally, the Singularities property allows you
            // to specify singularities or discontinuities
            // inside the integration interval. See the
            // sample below for details.

            //
            // Integration over infinite intervals
            // 

            integrator.AbsoluteTolerance = 1e-8;
            integrator.ConvergenceCriterion = ConvergenceCriterion.WithinAbsoluteTolerance;
            // The Integrate method performs the actual 
            // integration. To integrate over an infinite
            // interval, simply use either or both of
            // double.PositiveInfinity and 
            // double.NegativeInfinity as bounds:
            result = integrator.Integrate(x => Math.Exp(-x - x * x),
                double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

            Console.WriteLine("Exp(-x^2-x) on [-inf,inf]");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value:       {0}", integrator.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Exact value: {0}", Math.Exp(0.25) * Constants.SqrtPi);
            // To see whether the algorithm ended normally,
            // inspect the Status property:
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}", integrator.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}", integrator.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}", integrator.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}", integrator.EvaluationsNeeded);

            // If you just want the result, you can also call the Integrate
            // extension method directly on the integrand:
            Func<double, double> integrand = x => Math.Exp(-x - x * x);
            result = integrand.Integrate(double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
            Console.WriteLine("  Value:       {0}", result);

            //
            // Functions with singularities at the end points
            // of the integration interval.
            //

            // Thanks to the adaptive nature of the algorithm,
            // special measures can be taken to accelerate 
            // convergence near singularities. To enable this
            // acceleration, set the Singularities property
            // to true.
            integrator.UseExtrapolation = true;
            // We'll use the function that gives the Romberg
            // integrator in the BasicIntegration QuickStart
            // sample trouble.
            result = integrator.Integrate(x => Math.Pow(x, -0.9) * Math.Log(1 / x), 0.0, 1.0);
            Console.WriteLine("Singularities on boundary:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value:       {0}", integrator.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Exact value: 100");
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}",
                integrator.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}",
                integrator.EstimatedError);
            // Where Romberg integration failed after 1,000,000
            // function evaluations, we find the correct answer 
            // to within tolerance using only 135 function
            // evaluations!
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}",
                integrator.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}",
                integrator.EvaluationsNeeded);

            //
            // Functions with singularities or discontinuities
            // inside the interval.
            //
            integrator.UseExtrapolation = true;
            // We will pass an array containing the interior
            // singularities to the integrator through the
            // Singularities property:
            integrator.SetSingularities(1, Math.Sqrt(2));
            integrator.Integrate(x => x * x * x * Math.Log(Math.Abs((x * x - 1) * (x * x - 2))),
                0.0, 3.0);
            Console.WriteLine("Singularities inside the interval:");
            Console.WriteLine("  Value:       {0}", integrator.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("  Exact value: 52.740748383471444998");
            Console.WriteLine("  Status: {0}",
                integrator.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("  Estimated error: {0}",
                integrator.EstimatedError);
            Console.WriteLine("  Iterations: {0}",
                integrator.IterationsNeeded);
            Console.WriteLine("  Function evaluations: {0}",
                integrator.EvaluationsNeeded);

            Console.Write("Press Enter key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

доступный по [этому адресу](https://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/AdvancedIntegration.aspx)
Обе страницы достал загуглив название сайта и слово `Integration` выбрав в результатах поиска "Сохранённая копия".